# Plotting multiple lines from a data frame in R

Tags: r, graph, plot

I am building an R function to plot a few lines from a data table, I don't understand why this is not working?

```
data = read.table(path, header=TRUE);
plot(data$noop);
lines(data$noop, col="blue");
lines(data$plus, col="green");
```

I am reading the data from a file I has which is formatted like this:

```
 noop         plus         mins
 33.3         33.3         33.3
 30.0         40.0         30.0
 25.0         50.0         25.0
```

This is the minimal representation of the dataset, which contains more headers and more data points. So each of the rows of this data set reflects a sample taken at a given time. So my objective is to read this data in from the file, and then plot each column as a series of points connected by lines of different color.

The approach I am using currently is only plotting 1 line, and not multiple lines.

Comment: Can you share your data table (or some representative sample)?

Comment: Check this [Frequently Unread Suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/709529) for how to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at the ggplot2 package

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
data <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 23), noob = rnorm(24), plus = runif(24), extra = rpois(24, lambda = 1))
Molten <- melt(data, id.vars = "time")
ggplot(Molten, aes(x = time, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/ You'll find many examples of graphs and the corresponding code

Answer (score 11):

Or with base:

```
data <- data.frame(time = seq(0, 23), noob = rnorm(24), plus = runif(24), extra = rpois(24, lambda = 1))
plot(extra ~ time, 
  data = data, 
  type = "l", 
  ylim = c(min(data[ ,-1]), max(data[ ,-1])),
  ylab = "value")
lines(data$time, data$plus, col = "steelblue")
lines(data$time, data$noob, col = "pink")
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to load any package of for or apply, just simply use the matplot function built in R... Each column of a table will be a line in your graph (or symbols if you prefer).